# how to compare two input files using md5 in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, md5

how to compare two txt or pdf files in html or jsp using md5 algorithm? please post the code

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method=post action="nextpage.jsp">
<h3>Select File 1:</h3><input type="file" name="fileName1" id="file1">
<h3>Select File 2:</h3><input type="file" name="fileName2" id="file2">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" name="Compare" value="Compare">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my index.jsp file

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<%= request.getParameter("fileName1") %>
<%= request.getParameter("fileName2") %>
</body>
</html>
```

this is nextpage.jsp

i want to compare these two input files using message digest..
i have a java code of md5

```
public String msgDigest(String fname)throws Exception
{
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fname);
    byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];
    int nread = 0; 
        while ((nread = fis.read(dataBytes)) != -1) 
        {
                md.update(dataBytes, 0, nread);
            };
            byte[] mdbytes = md.digest();
         //convert the byte to hex format method 1
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++)
        {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            String result= sb.toString();
    return result;
}
```

how can i compare two files?

Comment: Show us `nextpage.jsp`.

Comment: i added nextpage.jsp to use servlet.i don't know servlet too. so left the idea

Answer (score 1):

I made a project that check the md5 of two files and show you the result. here are the codes.

the code for servlet :

```
@WebServlet("/upload")
@MultipartConfig
public class Md5ServletProcessor extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String md5ForFirstFile = getMd5String(request, "file1");
    String md5ForSecondFile = getMd5String(request, "file2");

    response.sendRedirect("result.jsp?file1Md5="+md5ForFirstFile+"&file2Md5="+md5ForSecondFile+"&filesEqual="+md5ForFirstFile.equals(md5ForSecondFile));

    }

  private String getMd5String(HttpServletRequest request, String parameter) throws ServletException, IOException{
    Part filePart = request.getPart(parameter); 
    InputStream is = filePart.getInputStream();
    return DigestUtils.md5Hex(is);
  }
}
```

jsp main page :

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Java MD5CheckSum</title>
 </head>

 <body> 
    <div>
        <h3> Choose Two Files for MD5CheckSum : </h3>
        <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>File 1:</th>
                <td><input type="file" name="file1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>File 2:</th>
                <td> <input type="file" name="file2" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <input type="submit" value="upload" />
        </form>          
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and finally the jsp result page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>Md5Checksum Result</title>
 </head>

  <body>
   <table>

    <tr>
       <th colspan="2">THE RESULT OF COMPARING TWO FILE IS:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><th colspan="2"></th></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>File1 Md5:</th>
            <td>${param.file1Md5}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>File2 Md5:</th>
            <td>${param.file2Md5}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>result</th>
            <td><c:if test="${param.filesEqual}">
                    <span style="color: green">These two files are equal</span>
                </c:if> <c:if test="${!param.filesEqual}">
                    <span style="color: red">These two files are not equal</span>
                </c:if></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
              <th colspan="2"><a href="." >go back</a></th>
        </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

for downloading the whole eclipse project you can use this link -> [link](https://app.box.com/s/qeb1kdocy62qxz1mq376)

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Commons FileUpload in servlet that processes form input. Here is sample tutorial: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html. Once you are done just dispatch to another jsp.

Is it sufficient for you to go further or do you need code sample?

Comment: You are welcome. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour so you know what to do next :-)